# How can I best enforce generic type constraint conditions?

Tags: .net, generics, constraints

I wrote a very simple class taking a generic parameter, say `T`. Now, I want to enforce that `T` can be only one of my custom types `ClassA`, `ClassB` and `ClassC`, so that I cannot mistakenly use it with meaningless types like `int`, `long` or even other classes I wrote. I thought that a way to do this would be making those three classes implement the same, empty `ISomething` interface and using a `where T : ISomething` in the generic class definition. However, I don't know if this approach (implementing an empty interface) makes any sense. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to enforce that only your types can be used if the generic class can't do anything with the type? Sounds more like you want to enforce the type usage in the class that uses your generic class.

Comment: Don't the classes share exposure of certain elements? If not, what it there relation to the generic class? What is there to discriminate between them? Currently you approach sounds far from ideal, but there isn't really enough information to provide you with details on what you _ought_ to do.

Comment: What is there about `ClassA` etc that makes it meaningful for them to be used in this generic class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not going to work. As `T` is of type `ISomething`, you only have access to the members of `ISomething` inside your generic class. As `ISomething` is only a marker interface without any members, it is of no use to you.
If your classes share common functionality, put this shared functionality into the interface. If they don't, they shouldn't implement the same interface and you should ask yourself about whether your design is right or not.
Please give a more specific example, maybe we can give more practical hints then.

Answer (score 1):

it depends what kind of constrain you wish to add and what kind of operation your class does.

In general you should add a constrain for the type your generic class uses

in the example below the generic class uses the method GetString() which is implemented in the base class. You need to add a constrain on that type to make sure the generic class will find that method

```
 class A
    {
        public string GetString()
        {
            return "A";
        }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public string GetAnotherString()
        {
            return "B";
        }
    }

    class GenericClass<T> where T:A
    {
        private T _obj;

        public GenericClass(T obj)
        {
            _obj = obj;
        }

        public string GetString()
        {
            return _obj.GetString();
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            GenericClass<A> genericClass=new GenericClass<A>(new B());
            Console.WriteLine(genericClass.GetString());
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```